# python imap not calling function for all items in list

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use python3.5 to parallelize CodeML by calling separate instances on different threads. I've gotten everything to work up to a point. If I provide `Pool.imap` (or `Pool.map`) with an iterable that contains more variables than cores the program has available, it will only run  one variable through each core and then exit. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

```
# Call CodeML for all files in a directory.
genes = glob(path + "06_phylipFiles/" + "*.phylip")
l = int(len(genes))
pool = Pool(processes = cpu)
func = partial(runCodeml, ap, usertree, path, completed, ctl, forward)
print("\n\tRunning CodeML with", str(cpu), "threads....\n")
rcml = pool.imap(func, genes, chunksize = int(l/cpu))       
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Basically, I need `Pool.imap` to run through the whole list before exiting.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem was with another program I was calling. I set that to run in a different step, so it runs on one thread before Pool.imap is called.